# Worksheet_Change multiple changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following question. I get an error if I delete multiple cells or perform a selection edit on multiple cells. My code is as follows;

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
    Sheets("log").Cells(80000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " heeft cel " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreviousValue & " to " & Target.Value & 
    End If

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If `Target` is a multi-cell range, then the comparison `Target.Value <> PreviousValue` will fail (`Target.Value` is then a 2D array).

Use a loop to compare each individual cell:

```
Dim rng as Range
For Each rng in Target
     If rng.Value <> PreviousValue Then
```